# FQL to relate friends like graphAPI does

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to know the time a user became friends with another user.

I am having a problem...  the field 'updated_time' in the graphAPI will give me (I think) the time that the friendship was changed (created).  like in

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dfriends.limit%2810%29.fields%28gender%2Cname%2Cupdated_time%29

I want to use FQL instead however, so that I can use the order_by parameter.  I can not find that field (updated_time) in the friend 'column' of the FQL simulacrum.  In fact only uid1 and uid2 are in the friend 'column'.  I can of course get information on the user (uid2) but that information does not relate it directly back to the other user.

Anyone have any help on this?

Comment: ok that 'updated_time' is not in fact the time that the friendship was initiated.  I am then at a loss for determining when the friendship started.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the time a friendship started from the `friend` table in FQL or the `friends` endpoint in the Graph API. Facebook has deliberately omitted these for security purposes.

The only way to find this is to query the `stream` FQL table or `feed` API endpoint and look for the announcement that you and the target user are now friends.

Comment: I understand.  out of curiosity, do you know what the 'updated_time' associated with the friends endpoint is?

Comment: It's not part of the `friends` endpoint, it is part of the `user` endpoint. It is the last time that user updated their profile.